# Play: the most concise form of JSON validation

Tags: playframework

I want to ask a question about the most concise way for JSON validation in Play! Framework

In official Play tutorials I've found topic about JSON Macro Inception. Its main idea for serialization / deserialization looks pretty nice:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

object Person{
  implicit val personFmt = Json.format[Person]
}
```

But what if I want to put here some validation constraints? For example I want to accept age 18 - 60? Should I return to standard `Writes` and `Reads` in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Were answers of help? If yes, don't forget to accept one of them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep all of the validation errors, yes. There appears to be `filter` and `filterNot` functions for [Reads](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Reads) where you can add your own validation errors, but they'll end up being just as verbose as defining the `Reads` this way:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

object Person{
    implicit val personFmt: Reads[Person] = (
        (__ \ "name").read[String] and 
        (__ \ "age").read[Int](Reads.min(18) keepAnd Reads.max(60))
    )(Person.apply _)
}
```

I'll typically define my `Reads` using the more verbose style above, and the `Writes` using the `Json.writes[T]` macro, as I usually don't need to constrain what's going back to the client.

Comment: Thanks, as I thought previously

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [JSON combinators](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonCombinators). For instance, you could validate a Person instance as follows:

```
implicit val PersonReads : Reads[Person] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "age").read[Int](min(18) keepAnd max(60))
)(Person.apply _)
```

You can also define your custom `Format[Person]` to be used for implicit conversion as well as a mix of `Reads[Person]` and `Writes[Person]`:

```
val personReads: Reads[Person] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "age").read[Int](min(18) keepAnd max(60))
)(Person.apply _)

val personWrites: Writes[Person] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "age").write[Int]
)(unlift(Person.unapply))

implicit val personFormat: Format[Person] =
  Format(personReads, personWrites)
```